# jQuery select time element with datetime attribute greater than 04-01-2020

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has several <time datetime='...'> ... </time> elements.  I'd like to use jQuery to select those elements with datetime attribute granter then today.  I used the following srcript without joy. Thanks for your help.

```js
$('time[new Date(datetime) > new Date.now()]').click(function(e){...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that with [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/), something like:

```
  $("time").filter(function() {
    return Date.parse($(this).attr("datetime")) > new Date();
  })
```